# Prevent 127.0.0.1 from going to proxy

Tags: 18.04, server

I am relatively new to ubuntu except the basics. It appears there is a proxy that is blocking my access to 127.0.0.1:2020. Basically I have 2 apps trying to communicate with each other on the same server and for some reason it is being directed through the proxy.

Is there a way to prevent 127.0.0.1 from going through the proxy?

Oct-20 - more info

So via curl I can call 127.0.0.1:4000 and communicate with the backend api. trace route is direct, no proxy involved.

However, if a backend api (127.0.0.1:3000) calls 127.0.0.1:4000 it hits the proxy and we get 407: ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED.

Why would localhost to localhost go through an external proxy? (again, no proxy is running locally)

Gina

Comment: `curl` may not have a proxy set up, whereas the rest of the system may have an http_proxy setup that your applications are obeying.  Can you run `echo $http_proxy; echo $https_proxy;` please and add the output to your question as an edit?  Also you'd need to share your backend API's configuration / code potentially to identify what to do here.

Comment: @ThomasWard There is no resulting output. Both backend apis are nodejs running on pm2.

Comment: looks like a pm2 issue. In my dump.pm2 file it lists http_proxy/https_proxy. Looking how to change.